# I am 16 years old boy & i don't want to get married because I like to live alone & i can control my sexual desires is it ok in Islam?

Tags: nikah

I am 16 years old boy & i don't want to get married because I like to live alone & i can control my sexual desires is it ok in islam ?

Answer (score 0):

salaamu alaikum,
Marriage is preferred but it is neither mandatory nor obligatory.

Allahu A'lam

Answer (score 0):

‏السلام عليكم

Marriage is a legal union between a man and woman without which they cannot be together. The Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) considered marriage to be a part of Sunnah, then added: “whoever turns away from my Sunnah is not from me.”
In another narration, he said: “O young people, those of you who can support a wife should marry, for marriage controls the gaze and protects the private parts from prohibited acts. And if one is unable to marry, he should fast for it is a shield.” (Bukhari and Muslim)

In al-Sharh al-Kabir, concerning obligatory marriage it says:

“If a person fears that he may commit fornication, it (marriage) is obligatory on him.” In Fath al-Wahhab, it says: “For the woman who has (physical) desires, marriage is sunnah, just as it is for the one who needs maintenance and the one who fears being taken advantage of by immoral persons.”

me speaking: if you think you’re going to have this mindset in a few years do as you please. but you can commit zina with your eye, ears, and hands. Masturbation is haraam. marriage is the best thing so you won’t fall into theses test. الله أعلم